# Excel: Sorting Data that is Custom Formatted to add a Prefix

Tags: excel, custom-formatting

Hi I have a list of Values in a table that I would like to Order, the data in the column has been compiled from three separate tables where the custom format was applied for example;

When I enter the value "2" the formatting adds the prefix "MCRY-" so the value I get is "MCRY-2".
But in another table it adds the prefix "ACCRY-"

When I copy this over into the "master" sheet the formatting is copied over to which is perfect, however when I order the column the formatting is ignored as the cell values are only the numbers and not the prefixes.

My question is, how do I get the sorting process to acknowledge the prefixes as if they are apart of the cell value?
So much so that is I have "MCRY-01", "ACCRY-01", "MCRY-02", "ACCRY-02" it will order it ACCRY and then MCRY.

I have tried special pasting as values but that doesn't work. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use conditional formatting for this process. You will need to hardcode. If "2" is in **A1** then put the following into **B1** to get the required result

`="MCRY-"&TEXT($A1,"00")`

Will give you "MCRY-02"

Comment: This would have been the way I would have done it but I cannot add any additional columns to the table so I only used the formatting option because it does not require additional cell usages.

Comment: Can you take the data elsewhere, create the strings from the numbers and then paste back in? or even create the strings in the master file. Otherwise I'm pretty sure it's not possible. Formatting is purposefully built to be ignored by excel functions and filters.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had some ‘lulus’ but this may count as my nastiest hack ever (@CallumDS33 is basically correct).

Format the “ACCRY-“ table with `"ACCRY-"#;"ACCRY-"@` then proceed as normal but add a helper column in your “master” sheet with:

```
=CELL("format",B1)
```

copied down to suit, where `B` is assumed to be the column to be ordered. Now sort on the column to be ordered within sorting of the helper column.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work? It just gives me value "F0"

Comment: I am getting "F0" for both "MCRY-" and "ACCRY-" formatted cells

Comment: Using "MCRY-"@ does not add the MCRY- prefix